# How can I overcame this 500 Server Internal Error when trying to pull google/appengine-java image for Managed VMs?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to run `gcloud --verbosity debug preview app setup-managed-vms` from yesterday with no success.

I am not the only one having this problem, but others post, found through google (not on SO) were never replied.

This is the stacktrace, with the verbosity set to debug level (it's long but at a certain time 2 rows start repeating themselves for like 50 times):

```
$ gcloud --verbosity debug preview app setup-managed-vms
DEBUG: Running gcloud.preview.app.setup-managed-vms with _Args({'base_image_bucket': 'containers-prod',
 'docker_host': None,
 'format': None,
 'h': None,
 'help': None,
 'image_version': 'latest',
 'markdown': None,
 'project': None,
 'quiet': None,
 'shell': None,
 'user_output_enabled': None,
 'verbosity': 'debug'}).
DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376, DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/Domenico/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2
INFO: Looking for image_id for image with tag google/docker-registry
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/images/json?filter=google%2Fdocker-registry&only_ids=1&all=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 253
DEBUG: Found Cloud SDK root: /Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk
Select the runtime to download the base image for:
 [1] Go
 [2] Java
 [3] Python27
 [4] All
Please enter your numeric choice (4):  DEBUG: Sent event: Event(category='Executions', action='gcloud', label=u'2014.12.02', value=0)
DEBUG: Sent event: Event(category='Commands', action='gcloud.preview.app.setup-managed-vms', label='unknown', value=0)
2

DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376, DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/Domenico/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2
Pulling base images for runtimes [java] from Google Cloud Storage
INFO: Refreshing access_token
DEBUG: Copy /Users/Domenico/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/xxxxxxxxxx.zzz@gmail.com/.boto to /var/folders/18/9rk3hmjs797fr0hfcr7qx5100000gn/T/tmpIXjpdT...
DEBUG: Copy /Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/docker/true-asm to /var/folders/18/9rk3hmjs797fr0hfcr7qx5100000gn/T/tmpIXjpdT...
INFO: Building image gcloud-credentials-image...
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/build?q=False&rm=True&t=gcloud-credentials-image&nocache=False HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO: Image gcloud-credentials-image built, id = 2d5b4c63b9fa
DEBUG: Full Image Build Log:
 ---> e72ac664f4f0
Step 1 : ADD true-asm /true
 ---> 7c1e01a097b3
Removing intermediate container cfb384a48ae1
Step 2 : RUN chmod +x /true
 ---> Running in ec660d02687a
 ---> f84fdff0f1ba
Removing intermediate container ec660d02687a
Step 3 : VOLUME /.config
 ---> Running in 26ad09bdaa9a
 ---> c540dddc963a
Removing intermediate container 26ad09bdaa9a
Step 4 : ADD .boto /.config/.boto
 ---> 3bd9a6606988
Removing intermediate container a6b42eb9c1a5
Step 5 : CMD /true
 ---> Running in cc8c5a1ee0cc
 ---> 2d5b4c63b9fa
Removing intermediate container cc8c5a1ee0cc
Successfully built 2d5b4c63b9fa

INFO: Creating container...
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (2): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/create?name=gcloud-credentials-1418138753.61 HTTP/1.1" 201 90
INFO: Container 44f316332dd39abaeaf50cbdb3ba14231e36323d914b085a50aa346c3e9d0bbd created.
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/44f316332dd39abaeaf50cbdb3ba14231e36323d914b085a50aa346c3e9d0bbd/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
INFO: Looking for image_id for image with tag google/docker-registry
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (3): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/44f316332dd39abaeaf50cbdb3ba14231e36323d914b085a50aa346c3e9d0bbd/attach?stderr=1&logs=1&stream=1&stdout=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/images/json?filter=google%2Fdocker-registry&only_ids=1&all=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 253
INFO: Creating container...
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/create HTTP/1.1" 201 90
INFO: Container 21c0d8f8eb7fa21bd14b8c6eebe4492a33d0f6d56f1f43560ead860b280fc909 created.
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/21c0d8f8eb7fa21bd14b8c6eebe4492a33d0f6d56f1f43560ead860b280fc909/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (4): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/21c0d8f8eb7fa21bd14b8c6eebe4492a33d0f6d56f1f43560ead860b280fc909/attach?stderr=1&logs=1&stream=1&stdout=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: Container: 21c0d8f8eb7f: Using credentials in /.config/.boto
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/containers/21c0d8f8eb7fa21bd14b8c6eebe4492a33d0f6d56f1f43560ead860b280fc909/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Pulling image: google/appengine-java
INFO: Pulling image google/appengine-java:latest from Google Cloud Storage...
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): localhost
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=localhost%3A49157%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine-java HTTP/1.1" 500 115
DEBUG: Exception 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://localhost:49157/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49157: connection reset by peer") thrown in pull. Retrying.
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): localhost
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=localhost%3A49157%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine-java HTTP/1.1" 500 120
DEBUG: Exception 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://localhost:49157/v1/_ping: net/http: transport closed before response was received") thrown in pull. Retrying.
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): localhost
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=localhost%3A49157%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine-java HTTP/1.1" 500 115
DEBUG: Exception 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://localhost:49157/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49157: connection reset by peer") thrown in pull. Retrying.
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): localhost
DEBUG: Container: 21c0d8f8eb7f: 2014-12-09 15:25:55,861 WARNING: Cache storage disabled!
DEBUG: Container: 21c0d8f8eb7f: 2014-12-09 15:25:55,861 WARNING: LRU cache disabled!
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=localhost%3A49157%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine-java HTTP/1.1" 500 115
DEBUG: Exception 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://localhost:49157/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49157: connection reset by peer") thrown in pull. Retrying.
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): localhost
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=localhost%3A49157%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine-java HTTP/1.1" 500 115
DEBUG: Exception 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://localhost:49157/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49157: connection reset by peer") thrown in pull. Retrying.
```

This last `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `DEBUG` sequence is repeated for like 40 times, till...

```
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): localhost
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=localhost%3A49157%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine-java HTTP/1.1" 500 115
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/21c0d8f8eb7fa21bd14b8c6eebe4492a33d0f6d56f1f43560ead860b280fc909/kill HTTP/1.1" 204 0
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/containers/44f316332dd39abaeaf50cbdb3ba14231e36323d914b085a50aa346c3e9d0bbd/kill HTTP/1.1" 204 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 171, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 385, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 928, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/setup_managed_vms.py", line 39, in Run
    args.image_version)
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/pull.py", line 54, in PullBaseDockerImages
    util.PullSpecifiedImages(docker_client, image_names, version, bucket)
  File "/Users/Domenico/Developer/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/util.py", line 232, in PullSpecifiedImages
    'Error pulling {image}: {e}'.format(image=image_name, e=e))
googlecloudsdk.appengine.lib.images.util.DockerPullError: Error pulling google/appengine-java: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://localhost:49157/v1/_ping: read tcp 127.0.0.1:49157: connection reset by peer")
```

I am running Docker version 1.3.0, as suggested in the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/).

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.3.0
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): c78088f
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.3.0
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): c78088f
```

and Google Cloud SDK v0.9.39

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.39

app 2014.12.02
app-engine-go-darwin-x86_64 1.9.17
app-engine-java 1.9.17
app-engine-managed-vms 2014.11.03
app-engine-python 1.9.17
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2014.12.02
core 2014.12.02
core-nix 2014.10.20
dns 2014.11.06
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.7
gsutil-nix 4.6
preview 2014.12.02
preview-extensions-darwin-x86_64 0.5
sql 2014.11.18
```

How can I overcame this error? Is this even avoidable or a bug on Google's end?

Comment: don't think this is a java issue. it looks like the install process is looking for a service to run at localhost:49157   are you sure it installed correctly?

Comment: I don't know what's supposed to run at localhost:49157. Docker, as the script can see, is running at 192.168.59.103:2376. If you look at the debug, the 20th-ish line says gcloud can correctly see that: `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376`.

Comment: Now that I think about it 49157 is a port Docker is supposed to use. Maybe the script reads the Docker location once from the env variable `DOCKER_HOST`, once from another place, and thus the issue. But I'm just saying...

Comment: It can be that /.config/.boto or any of the other .config locations listed in the debug contain something odd. The localhost:49157 might be a default config that gets reverted for some reason

Comment: I've the same issue!

Comment: Now I am also facing this same issue. Although I am not using boot2docker, rather I am using docker 1.2 on Ubuntu 14.10. Command: `gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms`

Comment: got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This `gcloud` command is now deprecated, please see the newest [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) for update instructions. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node-todos) for new instructions.